# ¿Cómo se puede compilar con GCC un programa de Gladec?

Tags: c, makefile

Vi unos videos de Youtube donde usaban Gladec con un Makefile y compilaban el programa, mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo se exporta como archivo C para posteriormente convertirlo en binario?

Comment: Según su [página de la Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glade), hace ya tiempo que `gladec` está discontinuado. ¿ De que fecha son esos vídeos ? Y en su [git](https://git.gnome.org/browse/glade/tree/) no hay ni rastro de dicha aplicación.

Comment: Apenas me entero de esa aplicación y en serio ya la cerraron? :O